# how to use background scheduler with an flask + gunicorn app

Tags: python, flask, cron, scheduler, gunicorn

I have one scheduler to send message periodically in my flask app. For gunicorn, I defined 10 sync workers and the app create 10 schedulers and send the same message 10 times. Is there any way to only send one message?
The code for flask app:

```
def send_msg():
     # here we send msg

@app.before_first_request
def activate_job():
     scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
     scheduler.add_job(send_msg, 'interval', minutes=5)
     scheduler.start()
     atexit.register(lamda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

Comment: Can you put some details about the message? Do you store this message in DB or something?

Comment: Use **one** `Queue` and let the the message sending workers draw from it. And as a hint from someone who builds microservices: if you need 10 background workers to do the task, think about off-loading the job with something like nameko or celery.

Comment: Is there a way you can separate the "background scheduler" logic off the flask app, so you can run it independently as a linux cron job? That's how it is supposed to be done, ideally.

Answer (score 4):

The 4 workers call the function activate job that's why your message was sent 4 times, I solved the problem by adding the background task in the main function that's called when I run my app and I added with app.app_context(): before the job function in your case

```
    def send_msg():
        with app.app_context():
            # here we send msg
```